# changing fontsize from `10px` to `14px` to `18px` with a single shortcut

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am creating a plugin for TinyMCE5 that toggles the fontsize of the selected text between `10px`, `14px` and `18px`. (The fontsize by defaut is `14px`)

This is my try:

```
editor.addCommand('customfontsize_command', function () {
var content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
var fontsize = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, 'font-size', true);

fontsize = fontsize.split("p", 1)
fontsize--;

if (fontsize > 0 && fontsize <= 100) { // only work for first time
    switch (fontsize) {
        case 18:
            fontsize = 14;
            break;
        case 10:
            fontsize = 8;
            break;
        case 8:
            fontsize = 18;
            break;
        default:
            fontsize = 14;
    }

    fontsize = fontsize + "px";
    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('fontsize', false, fontsize);
}
}); // end customfontsize_command
editor.addShortcut('alt+a', 'customfontsize_command_desc', 'customfontsize_command');
```

But it only works for the first time I do my shortcut.

I also tried this but with the same result:

```
if (fontsize > 10 && fontsize <= 14) { 
    fontsize = 10;
} else if (fontsize <= 10) {
    fontsize = 18;
} else {
    fontsize = 14;
}
```

---

I can make this work with 2 different shorcuts like this, but I would prefer a single shortcut that toggles between  the 3 sizes:

```
editor.addCommand('small_size', function () {
    var content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
    var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
    var fontsize = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, 'font-size', true);

    fontsize = fontsize.split("p", 1)
    fontsize = 10
    fontsize = fontsize + "px";
    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('fontsize', false, fontsize);

}); // end customfontsize_command


editor.addCommand('big_size', function () {
    var content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
    var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
    var fontsize = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, 'font-size', true);

    fontsize = fontsize.split("p", 1)
    fontsize = 18
    fontsize = fontsize + "px";
    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('fontsize', false, fontsize);

}); // end customfontsize_command
```

Comment: Single toggle meaning. in a single line ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
fontsize = (fontsize <= 10) ? 18 : ((fontsize > 10 && fontsize <= 14) ? 10 : 14);
```

Comment: yes, this is working, but I still don't understand why it didn't work with the `if else` or the `switch`

Comment: Great to hear :) Cheers